# VBA Code - Fast on one Computer, slow on another one

Tags: excel, performance, vba

I was writing a simple VBA macro that is checking all spreadsheets in a workbook if the entered values are correct (e.g. Only values >0 etc. -> no magic at all ;) )

Interestingly the code was running very fast on the target computer under this conditions:

The VBA code was stored in an own workbook (e.g. target_macro.xlsm) and the user had to type in the file url in a certain cell.

After embedding the code into the target workbooks + changing the code to use the ActiveWorkbook (because it should run locally), the code is running super slow on the target computer of the user (instead of ~20 Seconds it needs 10 minutes?!). On my machine it works as fast as before.

Any ideas why this can happen?

Comment: Could you show an outline of the code?

Comment: Sure that not the fast one is XLS (65536 x 256 cells per sheet) and the slow one is XLSX (1048576 x 16384 cells per sheet) and the macro runs over all cells in the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of stuff, I found the solution: A special addin caused the problem, which tried to connect to some network machine.

Answer (score 0):

VBA becomes slow if the file is on a Network drive. copy it to a local storage and it is multiple times faster.

I had this effect with MS Access databases and Excel spreadsheets - it speeded up the whole process of building data by a factor of 10 times.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that we already tried to copy the file on the local hard drive.

Still the same issiue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name or upload it on the cloud then download it, and then run it.
It will be faster than before.
it deletes the cache and runs like a new xlsm.

I also have the same problem. code runs on my computer and takes a lot of time. and when I shared to my another computer it runs 10 time faster than before.

I have redownloaded the same code to my pc and then run it. The code runs smoothly.